# Потоки ввода/вывода  Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

В Java для работы с потоками предусмотрены классы **InputStream**, **OutputStream** и их наследники.

Недавно я обнаружил, что параллельно существуют классы **Reader** и **Writer**, которые на первый взгляд дублируют друг-друга. Зачем они нужны? И чем они отличаются? Когда какой использовать? :)

Comment: это старые класы

Comment: InputStream, OutputStream - устаревшие ?

Comment: reader and writer, предпочтительнее использовать io/out stream

Comment: > reader and writer, предпочтительнее использовать i/o stream
почему вы так считаете?

Comment: советую прочитать про паттерн декоратор

Comment: > советую прочитать про паттерн декоратор

вы бы уточнили кому советуете :)

Comment: Я знаю про паттерн декоратор. Но мне кажется, что он используется и в I/O Stream и Reader/Writer. Насколько я понял отличие в том, что Reader и Writer позволяют проводить операции с 16-битными символами юникод.

Comment: @www, [здесь](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/readers-writers.html) IMHO толково написано.

Comment: @avp, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Reader/Writer` читают/пишут посимвольно, `InputStream/OutputStream` побайтово

Comment: Стоит добавить, что в большинстве случаев используют их буферизированные версии: BufferedReader/Writer